# Update cscope db and ctags for just modified files in large projects

Tags: ctags, cscope

Say I have around 100000 `*.c` `*.h` files in a `c project`. I am listing it into a cscope.files using `find` command and then creating the cscope.out and tags files from them as below.

```
1. find `pwd` -type f \( -name "*.c" -o -name "*.h" \) > cscope.files
2. /usr/bin/ctags -L cscope.files
3. cscope -b -i cscope.files -f cscope.out
```

To do so it taking 25 - 30 min time. If I modify single c file then if I want to update ctags then it taking around 20 min as I am updating entire `c project`(i.e step 2,3). So is there any way to update cscope.out and tags file faster by just updating them for changed c file.

Comment: Yes, I would definitely be interested in something like this too, fore my project it doesn't take quite that long but long enough that some incremental option would be helpful.... 
Did you get this resolved in any way @ypp ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use use ctags to generate tags for a set of files (that modification time is greater than .tags modification time) and append results to currently existing tags using --append switch:

```
ctags --recurse --verbose --append --extra=+q --fields=+aimS --c-kinds=+p --c++-kinds=+p -L list_of_files
```

More info: https://gist.github.com/Flolagale/5195934